# Вставить значение переменной в переменную с html форматированием

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt, qlabel

Подскажите пожалуйста, как передать значение одной переменной

`self.title = 'Link'`

в

`self.text_1 = ("<h3 style='color: red;'>`**`title`**`</h3>")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пожалуйста, всегда предоставляйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Я не уверен, что правильно понял, то что вы хотите сделать. Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class Window(QFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()        
        
        self.title = 'Link'
        
        self.label =  QLabel(alignment=Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setText(f"<h1 style='color: red;'>{self.title}</h1>")            # <---- 
      
        gridLayout = QGridLayout(self) 
        gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо!!! помогло

Comment: @matyash пожалуйста